# Custom Review star images not showing properly in Swift

Tags: swift, for-loop, floating-point, uiimageview

I have taken 5 imageviews in storyboard and connected outlets like this

```
@IBOutlet var starRatingImageViews: [UIImageView]!
```

and i am getting string value from json for *rating* like this `rating = "4.2"`

for eg. `rating = "4.2" i need to show 4 full stars and one half star` but its not showing properly

o/p: here i have "4.2" rating but its stars showing wrongly in output. please guide me to fix this issue

[image]

**code:** here `user.rating = "4.2"` but showing wrong stars in o/p. where am i wrong in `fillStars` method. please do guide.

```
 @IBOutlet var starRatingImageViews: [UIImageView]!

 if let rating = Float(user.rating ?? "0.0") {
     rating.fillStars(in: starRatingImageViews)
 }

 func fillStars(in imageViews: [UIImageView], withEmptyStar color: UIColor = .darkGray) {
    for i in (0 ..< imageViews.count) {
        imageViews[i].contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        let review = Int(Float(self))
        if (i < review) {
            imageViews[i].image = UIImage(systemName: "star.fill")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal).withTintColor(CommonColor.yellowColor)
        } else {
            if (self - Float(review)) > (0.5), i == review {
                imageViews[i].image = UIImage(systemName: "star.fill")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal).withTintColor(CommonColor.yellowColor)
            } else if (self - Float(review)) <= (0.5), (self - Float(review)) > (0.0), i == review {
                imageViews[i].image = UIImage(systemName: "star.leadinghalf.fill")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal).withTintColor(CommonColor.yellowColor)
            } else {
                imageViews[i].image = UIImage(systemName: "star")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal).withTintColor(color)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `self - Float(review)` to figure out what kind of star to draw, but `self` is independent of your loop, and you're not even consistent about it, since you use `i < review` as the first test.  You can make that work, but it's harder than it needs to be. The matter is confused somewhat more by having more cases than you need: You either need to draw a filled star, a half-filled star, or an empty star.  That's 3 cases, but you have 4 in your code, because you duplicate the full star case.

In comments you clarified that `let review = Int(Float(self))` is converting from `String`.  So let's look at what happens when `self` is supposed to be `"4.2"` and `i` is 3, which is where it incorrectly computes the partial star.  In this case `review` will be 4, so `if i < review` *should* be `true` since 3 is less than 4, so it should set `imageViews[i]` to a full star, but it doesn't actually do that. This tells me that `self` is *not* `"4.2"`, and therefore `review` is not `4`.  Either print `self` or put a break-point on the `if` to see what `self` and `review` actually are.  That will probably show you your bug.  Based on that, I think your assumptions about what `self` is are likely incorrect somehow.

Even after fixing that, though, `fillStars` still has a bug, because when `i` is 4, that is on the last star, it completely fills it, but it should be empty.

Nonetheless, `fillStars` could be simpler.

When I have problems like this, I prefer to think in terms of calculating the percent of the current indicator (star, in your case) that needs to be drawn, and then use that result to decide what to do, rather than mixing the calculation and decision-making together.  So I would modify your code to be something like this:

```swift
func clamp<T: Comparable>(_ value: T, to range: ClosedRange<T>) -> T {
    return max(range.lowerBound, min(range.upperBound, value))
}

func fillStars(
    in imageViews: [UIImageView],
    withEmptyStar color: UIColor = .darkGray)
{
    let review = Float(self) // Is this needed now?

    for i in imageViews.indices
    {
        imageViews[i].contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        let tintColor: UIColor
        let starName: String
        
        // Calculate the percentage of the current star to draw
        let percentOfThisStar = clamp(review - Float(i), to: 0...1)

        // Now use the percentage to pick the image/tinting
        if percentOfThisStar == 0
        { // Empty star
            tintColor = color
            starName  = "star"
        }
        else
        {
            tintColor = CommonColor.yellowColor
            starName  = percentOfThisStar < 0.5
                ? "star.leadinghalf.fill" // Partial star
                : "star.fill"             // Full star
        }
        
        imageViews[i].image = UIImage(systemName: starName)?
            .withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
            .withTintColor(tintColor)

    }
}
```

As a suggestion, I'd probably move `fillStars` to another part of your code base.  I'm not exactly sure what `self` is (`Float`? `Double`? `Decimal`?), except that it's some numeric type, and it seems `fillStars` is a method in an extension on whatever that numeric type is. I'd probably just make it free function instead, or maybe a method in whatever view contains the stars, and pass the `review` in as a parameter.  My reasoning is just that filling stars doesn't have much to do with being any of the numeric types that `self` might be.  It's just a special case usage for your app, probably just for one specific view in your app, so why not put it in that view?  Or as a top-level app-specific function?  Obviously that's a judgement call.  The compiler doesn't care, so it's just a matter of what makes the most sense for you and your team.

To make life a little easier to test it without creating a full-on app (and to avoid having to use Simulator), I wrote it like this in a command line tool:

```swift
enum StarType: String
{
    case empty   = "[  ]"
    case partial = "[* ]"
    case filled  = "[**]"
}

func clamp<T: Comparable>(_ value: T, to range: ClosedRange<T>) -> T {
    return max(range.lowerBound, min(range.upperBound, value))
}


func fillStars(
    in stars: inout [StarType],
    from rating: Float)
{
    assert(Float(stars.count) >= rating)
    
    for i in stars.indices
    {
        // Calculate the percentage of the current star to draw
        let percentOfThisStar = clamp(rating - Float(i), to: 0...1)

        // Now use the percentage to set the star type
        let starType: StarType
        if percentOfThisStar == 0
        { // Empty star
            starType = .empty
        }
        else
        {
            starType  = percentOfThisStar < 0.5
                ? .partial
                : .filled
        }
        
        // This could have been done in the `if`, but doing it here allows
        // easier refactoring to UIImageView, if that's desired.
        stars[i] = starType
    }
}
```

I renamed `review` to be `rating`, and pass it in as a parameter.  Instead of a filled star, I print `[**]`, for a partial star I print `[* ]` and for an empty star I print `[  ]`.

I drive it with this code:

```swift
var stars: [StarType] = .init(repeating: .empty, count: 5)
let rating: Float = 4.2
fillStars(in: &stars, from: rating)
let starStr = stars.map { $0.rawValue }.joined()

print("rating = \(rating), stars = \(starStr)")
```

These are the results:

```
rating = 4.2, stars = [**][**][**][**][* ]
```

Which appears to be the correct result.

As mentioned above, based on what you've described, I think there is at least one bug that happens *before* calling `fillStars`.

Comment: actually `user.rating = 4.2` is a string value i am converting that into float...and `fillStars` method is in another file with inside `extension Float {}`

Comment: `fillStars` method in ExtraFunctionality file i am calling that in ProfileViewcontroller

Comment: I have added your code still getting same review like above o/p screenshot.. could you guide me

Comment: I added a refactored example so I could run it in a command line tool (or playground, but command line tools are less problematic than playgrounds), along with the driver code.  Since the refactored version doesn't use UIKit, it just prints text for the stars (ie: `[  ]`, `[* ]`, and `[**]`).   The logic, however, is unchanged.  I'm happy to help, but but try using the refactored version, using the resulting `[StarType]` to set your `[UImageView]`.

Comment: BTW - I only take `stars` as an `inout` parameter to sort of mimic your original API, but in this form, it could just construct a `[StarType]` internally and return it, though passing it in as an `inout` does allow for better performance, if it gets called a large number of times in rapid succession, since it allows you to avoid superfluous memory allocations.

Comment: I added some analysis if what should happen in your code if `self` were `"4.2"`.  My conclusion is that it can't be `"4.2"` which means `review` is probably set wrong.  That suggests some problem in the calling code.